# How to deploy Approval processes using ANT migration tool?

Tags: ant, approval-process

I am trying make a deployment using ant, i have an error concerning Approval processes, i am wondering if we can really deploy an approval process using ANT:

```
All Component Failures:
1.  package.xml -- Error: ApprovalProcess cannot be a component in a managed or unmanaged package. Remove ApprovalProcess from package.xml to deploy unpackaged components.
```

Do you know why ?

Comment: My guess is that your package.xml has a fullName member; approval processes can't be in a package.

Comment: Yes that is, i just delete the FullName memeber and it worked, thank you   sfdcfox

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you add fullName to a package.xml, the metadata API assumes you're trying to insert/update a package instead of deploying unpackaged metadata. You must not specify fullName when deploying components that cannot be packaged.

Comment: - whats this fullname?

Comment: oh i think i know what you meant by fullname. is it the approvers NAME?

Comment: @OK999 No, the OP added a "fullName" attribute to their package.xml, which resulted in an error message. You cannot package approval processes, so attempting to create a project with it generates an error.

Comment: ok got it .. never expected that attribute :)

Comment: @OK999 Most people have probably never used it, it's mostly for ISVs, but it's something good to know if you need it.

Comment: but this attribute is populated from some entry while creating a changeset. And we download the changeset locally